# Show different value based on Checkbox tick

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have 2 checkboxes and 1 cell

When checkbox 1 is ticked I want to show "Checkbox 1 selected" in the cell

When checkbox 2 is ticked I want to show "Checkbox 2 selected" in the cell

`=OR((A1,"Checkbox 1 selected",""),(A2,"Checkbox 2 selected",""))`

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go. You were missing the `IF`s.

You should `JOIN` the functions instead of using `OR` which returns `TRUE` or `FALSE`, not the text you are trying to get from your `IF` functions.

```
=JOIN(", ",IF(A1,"Checkbox 1 selected",""),IF(A2,"Checkbox 2 selected",""))
```

---

If you will never have both checked at once, this formula will be shorter.

```
=IF(A1,"Checkbox 1 selected",IF(A2,"Checkbox 2 selected",""))
```

Comment: Thanks SOOO MUCH! OMG!